# NPAPI plugin have high cpu usage in Mac safari

Tags: npapi

I use to NPAPI for video streaming.

But in Mac Safari (Mt.Lion, v6.0.2), it have high cpu usage (7~80%) when loading.
Chrome or FireFox is normality.

I guess when call NPNFuncs.invalidaterect function.

```
int16_t PLUGINAPI::handleEvent(void* event)
{
    NPCocoaEvent* cocoaEvent = (NPCocoaEvent*)event;
    ScriptablePluginObject* pObject = (ScriptablePluginObject*)m_pScriptableObject;


    if(cocoaEvent->type == NPCocoaEventDrawRect) {
        CGContextRef cgContext = cocoaEvent->data.draw.context;

        if(!cgContext)
            return true;

        //Add rect and translate the video
        CGContextAddRect(cgContext, CGRectMake (0, 0, m_Window->width, m_Window->height));
        CGContextTranslateCTM(cgContext, 0, m_Window->height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(cgContext, 1.0, -1.0);

        //Display the video here
        if(pObject && pObject->m_pNpapiPlugin) 
            pObject->m_pNpapiPlugin->WEBVIEWER_DisplayFrame(cgContext, m_Window->width, m_Window->height);

        //Fulsh cgcontextref
        CGContextFlush(cgContext);

        //Generate DrawRect event
        NPRect rect = {0, 0, m_Window->height, m_Window->width};
        NPNFuncs.invalidaterect(m_pNPInstance, &rect);
        NPNFuncs.forceredraw(m_pNPInstance);

    } else {

        if(pObject && pObject->m_pNpapiPlugin)
            pObject->m_pNpapiPlugin->WEBVIEWER_SendEvent(cocoaEvent);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is there another way for plugin drawing? or I want solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling it to redraw as fast as it can!

```
NPNFuncs.invalidaterect(m_pNPInstance, &rect);
NPNFuncs.forceredraw(m_pNPInstance);
```

When you call this it will trigger another draw event. Safari probably redraws faster than the other browsers, and that might be why you are using so much CPU. Basically what you are saying is "each time you draw, draw again immediately!".

Instead of calling invalidateRect and forceRedraw from your draw handler (which you should never do!) set up a timer. Remember that if you're drawing more than 60 frames per second you're probably wasting CPU cycles because most displays only refresh that fast.  I generally recommend 30fps as a max for most things, but that's between you and the video card.